# After deployment of ASP.NET Core 2.2 application to IIS sessions using HttpContext.Session aren't working

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

After deploying my ASP.NET Core 2.2 application using IIS, sessions, which are codeded using HttpContext.Session aren't working. If I set a session variable, as soon as the request ends, variable is deleted and if I try to access it after with different request, the value of the variable is null. While if I run the app in visual studio everything works.

Comment: You need to post some code, at the bare minimum: your startup. My best guess with nothing to see is that you have not configured a persistent session store like Redis or SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that unless you want all cookies to not require consent. To allow the session, you should only add the option `Cookie.IsEssential = true` in `AddSession`. This will mark session cookies as essentials.

```
services.AddSession(options => {
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

Read this for more info: https://andrewlock.net/session-state-gdpr-and-non-essential-cookies/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that IIS decided that session cookie was not essential and I had an option enabled to require user permission to use non-essiantial cookies. Because I only use essential cookies, I just changed this `options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;` to this `options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;` in Startup.cs